# How to track progress of AWS s3 upload when done using presigned_post_url()?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am uploading files to amazon s3 storage using Python SDK using Presigned POST. It uploads but how do I track the progress. In terms of Boto, I am not getting any good articles to proceed.

Comment: What are you using to upload the file? A front end?

Comment: I am generating a presigned POSt URL and sending it to front end/ browser.

Comment: You can track the progress in the front end then.

Comment: Are there any good examples for that? If you have any links that will help a lot

Comment: Depends on your front end. What are you using for front end?

Comment: i am using javascript

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196705/discussion-between-varun-singh-and-ninad-gaikwad).

Comment: http://www.tothenew.com/blog/aws-s3-file-upload-with-progress-bar-using-javascript-sdk/

Comment: Any answer to this? I am dealing with a similar situation. I am generating the preSignedUrl from my node server sending it to the front end and using axios to put the request to s3 but I am not sure how to get progress.